# "DOCTYPE expected" error in windows HTML5 app while opening document

Tags: jquery, html, doctype, windows

I am creating **Windows 8.1 App using Javascript and HTML5** in Visual studio. so, to open a document from the site i am using .

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JS_BlankApp</title>
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="phone">
    <div>
        <x-ms-webview id="webview" src="http://google.com" width="300" height="300"></x-ms-webview>
    </div>
     <div style="background-color:yellow">
        <a href="#" id="OpenDocument">Click here to open the document</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Javascript code:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

    app.onactivated = function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#OpenDocument").click(function () {
                        //$("webview").attr("src", m");
                        webview.navigate("https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13226_01/workshop/docs81/pdf/files/workshop/JavaKeywordReference.pdf")
                    });
                });

            } else {
            }
            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
        }
    };

    app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {

    };
    app.start();
})();
```

The issue is when i click on "OpenDocument" link i get the following error in my console window:

> HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype:
>   "".

Can some one suggest me what's wrong i am doing.?

Comment: Sounds like there might be some characters (possibly hidden) before the `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: @ChuckLeButt How can i identify that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a local issue as I have not been able to duplicate it. Removing the `<!DOCTYPE html>` would fix the issue.

Comment: When i removed the <!DOCTYPE html> i am getting two errors. First is: The top level document requested the <5> doc mode, but the system enforces the <11> doc mode. The app will use the <11> doc mode to display the document.      and second is:  DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "<!DOCTYPE html>".